# Probability of equal no. of red/black cards from selection - simulation vs. answers discrepancy

Tags: probability, simulation

Following reading this thread: "[Probability of drawing exactly 13 black & 13 red cards from deck of 52](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024175/probability-of-drawing-exactly-13-black-13-red-cards-from-deck-of-52/2270952#2270952)", I created a simple simulation using Excel/VBA to help my son grasp the concept - he's only 7 but wanted to know more...

In this simulation, I chose 2, 4, 6...50 cards from a deck of 52 over 10,000 iterations each and counted how many events of equal red/black cards occurred for each round. The chance of equal red/black cards were then recorded and graphed - results as follows:

- [Excel graph of simulated probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QB3g.jpg)

These results are in no way remotely close to the solutions given to the [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024175/probability-of-drawing-exactly-13-black-13-red-cards-from-deck-of-52/2270952#2270952). However, to me the simulated results are logical (2 should be the same as 50, 4 the same as 48 etc.). So where have I/we gone wrong?

- [Numeric comparison of sim results - P(Sim) - and solutions given to the original post - P(Ans).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRcvz.jpg)

Unfortunately my high school days were too long ago to address the deterministic answer. However, I am (supposed to be) an expert at simulations and this problem is a very basic one to perform.

I guess it boils down to my disputing the provided answers: ie. for 10 selected cards, the solution of (10C5)^2/(52C10) ~ 0.0004%, nothing like 27.82% from the sim. Logically this should also equal 42 selected cards (10 left over) but the provided answer calculates as (42C21)^2/(52C42) ~  1.83E+13.

So if anyone can resolve the differences or point out to me where I've missed something, that would be wonderful.

Many thanks and regards,
David E

Answer (score 4):

The chance of getting five red and five black is $\frac {{26 \choose 5}^2}{52 \choose 10} \approx 0.2735$, very close to your simulation.  The $26 \choose 5$s are the number of ways to choose five of the $26$ red (black) cards.

Comment: Yes - there's the answer! It's (26C5)^2/(52C10), not (10C5)^2/(52C10). Thank you Ross. No wonder the solution for 26 drawn cards was close to my simulated result! Cheers - David - PS. One day I'll learn to use mathematical notation...

Comment: @deldridg for help with formatting: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for this - finally worked it out.